Is scikit-image resize() affected by the bit depth of the image?
I'm trying to preprocess some data for a computer vision project, and I've been doing so by resizing all the images in a directory. Before flattening them and creating a numpy array containing said processed images.
import os
from skimage.transform import resize
from skimage.io import imread
import numpy as np

img_array = imread(os.path.join(path, img))
img_resized = resize(img_array, (150, 150, 3))
flat_data_arr.append(img_resized.flatten())
flat_data = np.array(flat_data_arr)

when I run this code, I get the following error:
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (12500,) + inhomogeneous part.

I went in and manually printed the size of each image in flat_data_arr, and realized that all but one of them had a size of 67500, with the sole outlier being 202500. That image has a bit depth of 8, while the rest of my images have a bit depth of 24.
Would this explain the discrepancy, and is there any way I can avoid this error besides just manually finding and deleting images with a different bit depth? Thanks!

Huh – bit depth of eight connotes a single-channel grayscale image. And look, I love scikit-image but I can’t be the first to note that its API is not exactly rationally consistent. It looks like it isn’t a bit-depth thing, per se – but an image-channel thing. If you have a good suite of test images (including various bit-depths and modes) you can do a quick test script using your existing analysis to figure it out. Another thing you can employ is Pillow: all Pillow (née PIL) images can be seamlessly represented as NumPy arrays, and vice versa. Pillow has a ton of channel-y functions!

Well, certainly if your bit depth is 8, then it makes no sense at all to resize to (150,150,3).  That will scramble the pixels.

@TimRoberts exactly, and that seems to have been what happened here. In NumPy one should check the shape; if Pillow/PIL is in play, the mode property of the image can be examined. But any assumption about the nature of the image data will screw things up down the line in the case of logic like this.

[mre] required. flat_data_arr is undefined. please review the article carefully.
